# How to pass template of Anythings as template parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, types, auto

To have any types in template one may just write `template <typename ...> struct S {};`.

To have any values (e.g. `int` values) in template one may write `template <auto ...> struct S {};`.

To have template of any types in template one writes `template <template <typename ...> class Tmpl> struct S {};`.

But how to have template of Anythings in template? Anythings meaning 1) types or 2) values or 3) other templates of Anythings? I.e. mix everything what is possible inside template.

I.e. how to write `template <template <Anything ...> class Tmpl> struct S {};`

types/values/templates can be mixed in any order inside `Tmpl` parameters list.

One use case for having such structure `S` that accepts any kind of template is to implement template traits, i.e. so that `S` can tell somehow 1) how many parameters Tmpl has. 2) for each of parameter (by index) it can tell if it is type or value or another template.

Another use case for `S` is that it is needed to implement rich compile time information. I.e. if I can tell all the information about passed-in template, how many and what params it has, then I can compose composite Type Id or Type Name recursively and thus have compile time type reflection.

Also I'm interested in knowing how to intermix at least types and values inside one template in arbitrary order? I.e. how to have `template <TypeOrValue ... Args> struct S {};`? Here `TypeOrValue` signifies either `typename` or `auto` in any order or count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you cannot do what you're asking for. But what you can do is represent values as a special type, and then intermix that special type with other "normal" types. E.g., a helper could look something like this (untested code):

```
template<auto v>
struct value {};
```

Then any occurrence of `value<...>` would indicate that a value was meant, not a type. Doing anything useful with this can be finicky as you would have to handle `value<...>` specially, but it can work.

Comment: Thanks! Nice variant. Although can't solve my task for having generic compile time type info and traits library, because it can't handle any user defined type. But for specially created types with your `value` usage it can be a nice solution!

Comment: `template<auto x>using value_t=std::integral_constant< std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x >;` is a good choice for this (or roll your own).  And `template<auto x>constexpr value_t<x> value={};` is also quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

You could write hana style metaprogramming where everything is a constexpr function taking and returning values, with wrappers/unwrappers to convert to-from template metaprogramming at each end.  But that just moves the work into the wrappers.

Comment: Even `template <TypeOrValue ... Args> struct S {};` is not possible to implement? TypeOrValue means `auto` or `typename`.

Comment: @arty Asking the question again won't change the answer.  Well maybe if you wait for C++26 or something, but not in 5 minutes.